# How make Gini coefficient graph in R with and without NTFPs?

Tags: r

I am trying to make Gini coefficient in Lorenz curve graph. Please show me how to do it, step-by-step. I want to do income inequalities with in NTFPs (Non-Timber Forest Products) and without it. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.